# Can't change display driver on Ubuntu 22.04 after installation failed

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 22.04

Similar to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1235698/cant-change-display-driver-on-ubuntu-20-04) question about Ubuntu 20.04, the list of additional drivers is greyed out and I can not change the driver. Currently "continue using a manually installed driver" is selected.

I first installed nvidia-driver-535, I also managed to install the cuda drivers for it.
Then I wanted to change the driver to nvidia-driver-550. So I selected the driver and hit "Apply Changes". During the installation, an error message appeared saying that something had failed. I didn't understand what the problem was and I also forgot to take a screenshot. The problem with that error message was that I could not close it but using [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65457/window-too-big-cant-resize-or-maximize) question I was able to somehow reach the "close" button.

But then the problem of this question happend.

Answer (score 1):

## TL;DR

Use this command if you installed the driver via "Additional drivers" tab of the "Software & Updates"

```bash
sudo ubuntu-drivers install nvidia:VERSION
```

where `VERSION` is the version you want to install.

## Full answer

The command (as suggested by [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1235806/1042387w))

```bash
sudo apt purge 'nvidia.*'
```

did **not** work as the driver was not installed via `apt` but via the "Additional drivers" tab of the "Software & Updates" application.

I was able to install the driver (nvidia-driver-550) using the command (I found [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1461125/1042387))

```bash
sudo ubuntu-drivers install
```

This was probably working because 550 is the currently latest version. In case you want to install a specific version, use this command:

```bash
sudo ubuntu-drivers install nvidia:VERSION
```

where `VERSION` is the version you want to install. It might be that some versions are not compatible with certain kernel versions as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1461125/1042387).

### Steps

Now to the steps of what I had to do:

Enter the installation command into the

```bash
sudo ubuntu-drivers install
```

This might take a while to download. After the download finished, the terminal was going blank (i.e. all characters and symbols disappeared). I panicked a bit but everything was actually fine. Then a "terminal screen" appeared to setup **secure boot**.

In case you have already done this, it might be that the remaining of this question (except maybe a reboot) is not needed.

Using the arrow-keys and <kbd>TAB</kbd> (select) and <kbd>Enter</kbd> (confirm) one can navigate the menus that are presented. In the menu it prompts you to setup a password which you have to enter after a reboot to confirm you are allowed to do this change.

Enter the password once and contine, then reenter the same password again for confirmation.

After the process is done, the terminal can be closed and the computer has to be rebooted.
There (at least on my system) a screen appeared with multiple options, including "enroll MOK". Select this option. After that you can view the key, as I knew what it was about I just confirmed. Then one has to enter the password previously setup for secure boot. Once this step is done, select "reboot".

After the reboot the driver should be installed correctly.